# Zip Multiple Text Files from Multiple Directories into One ZIP File in One Command in Bash

Tags: bash, zip, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an account on AWS and I use S3 for storing data.  I have commands that will enable me to zip data files like so:

```
data.zip s3_dir/level-1/level-2/*/*/data.txt
```

But there are, say, 50 or more levels.  I want to zip all the data.txt files together from all levels.  I'm not as sharp on my Bash as I could be so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: does it have to be a zip file? Can you use [gzip](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/gzip.1.asp) instead? It's not the same format, but I know it can be recursive with the -r option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find some/dir -name data.txt | zip -@ data.zip
```

Comment: This is perfect...  Actually, right after I posted this question, a buddy gave me some hints...  The command I used was: `find /some/path -name '*.txt' | xargs -n 100 zip all_data.zip`

Comment: What's the `-@` for BTW?

Comment: It tells `zip` to get the list of filenames from stdin, so that you don't need to use `xargs`.